# How can I setup multiple Django Apps using Supervisor (including Gunicorn and Nginx)? bind() to [::]:8090 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: linux, nginx, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I already deployed a Django/Wagtail App using Supervisor, Gunicorn and Nginx (on Debian Buster), so I can reach it with http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/cms

server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8090;
    listen [::]:8090 ipv6only=on;
    error_log /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-error.log;
    access_log /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-access.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/www.mysite.com/www/my-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }
        location /media/ {
        root /home/www.mysite.com/www/my-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/guni-mysite-admin.conf

[program:guni-mysite-admin]
command=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/bin/gunicorn admin_panel.wsgi:application --config /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/etc/gunicorn/conf.py
user=www.mysite.com
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx-mysite-admin.conf

[program:nginx-mysite-admin]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/nginx-error.log
stdout_logfile=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/nginx-access.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=2MB
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=2MB
```

```
/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/etc/gunicorn/conf.py

workers = 3
keepalive = 5
user = 'www.mysite.com'
proc_name = 'admin_panel'
loglevel = 'error'
errorlog = '/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-error.log'
accesslog = '/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-access.log'
bind = 'unix:/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/run/gunicorn.sock'
raw_env = ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=admin_panel.settings.production']
pythonpath = '/home/www.mysite.com/www/mysite/cms/admin_panel'
```

Now I added 2 more Django Apps the same way. Unfortunately Supervisor can´t bring them up. Sometimes 1 out of 3 runs, but most of the time none of them work. In case it works it creates 3 processes (idk if that´s how it is supposed to be).

```
$ sudo lsof -i:8090

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   3631     root   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3631     root   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3632 www-data   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3632 www-data   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3633 www-data   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3633 www-data   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
```

Nginx error log gives *98: Address already in use*, even on port 81 (took it as default port because Apache is using 80), which is not used. Apache should not be the problem, because it doesn´t work, even when Apache is turned off.

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log

...
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:4020 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8090 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8070 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:4030 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24928#24928: still could not bind()
...
```

### Output - # nginx -T

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf:
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/admin.mysite_2:
server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 4020;
    listen [::]:4020 ipv6only=on;
    error_log /home/www.mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-CiomF2CE/var/log/gunicorn-error.log;
    access_log /home/www.mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-CiomF2CE/var/log/gunicorn-access.log;

    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mysite_2/www/translator-app-python/cms/wagtail_cms;
    }
        location /media/ {
        root /home/mysite_2/www/translator-app-python/cms/wagtail_cms;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-CiomF2CE/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/proxy_params:
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cms:
server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8090;
    listen [::]:8090 ipv6only=on;
    error_log /home/mysite_1/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-error.log;
    access_log /home/mysite_1/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-access.log;

    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mysite_1/www/kc-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }
        location /media/ {
        root /home/wmysite_1/www/kc-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mysite_1/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    # alte Syntax
    listen 81 default_server;
    listen [::]:81 ipv6only=on default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/Nginx;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php ;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server ( neu )
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kcanalytics:
server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8070;
    listen [::]:8070 ipv6only=on;
    root /home/mysite_1/www/kc-site/Open-Web-Analytics;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/kcanalyticslog/kcanalytics-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/kcanalyticslog/kcanalytics-access.log;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kcclient:
server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080 ipv6only=on;
    root /var/www/html/Nginx;
    index index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phrases-api.mysite_2:
server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 4030;
    listen [::]:4030 ipv6only=on;
    error_log /home/mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-dAF0CRIW/var/log/gunicorn-error.log;
    access_log /home/mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-dAF0CRIW/var/log/gunicorn-access.log;

    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mysite_2/www/translator-app-python/api/translator_rest_api;
    }
        location /media/ {
        root /home/mysite_2/www/translator-app-python/api/translator_rest_api;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mysite_2/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-dAF0CRIW/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using supervisord?

Comment: by the way `listen 8090;    listen [::]:8090 ipv6only=on;` tells to listen on that port, why not change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nginx is complaining for the IPV6 address only. Do you need ipv6 at all? If you don't, then removing the listen blocks for ipv6 will make nginx start properly only on ipv4. If you DO need IPV6 listeners in nginx, then you can do the following

```
fuser -k 8090/tcp
```

This will kill the PID holding port 8090. Do the same for the rest of the ports you need. A more harsh approach would be to kill nginx completely (supposing it's the one holding the ports open)

```
pkill -f nginx & wait $!
service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks you´re right but I need to keep IP settings like this for sake of having control over IPv4 and IPv6 bindings. With following setup I successfully run two clients, three API´s, a Wordpress and Php Analytics Site without conflicts: As an example one of the API´s has Apache2 HTTP Server as Proxy (listening to port 80) which is forwarding to Nginx (not controlled by Supervisor which actually is the solution!) Gunicorn is conntrolled by Supervisor.